# Android SDK - Get data from Document Variable/XML file

Tags: android, xml

I have an XML file which I have retrieved the data via a Document variable. I need to extract data for a class which contains several fields. What is the easiest way to retrieve the records from the Document variable ?

Answer (score 0):

For `Document` objet use `DOM` parser.

For XML files use `SAX` parser.

Try to use a `SAX` parser for XML parsing, because it is more memory efficient.